# Rabbitmq exchange point subscription

Tags: rabbitmq

A question about architecture of data flows in RabbitMQ

Is it possible to collect messages from different queues to one exchange point?
And later consumers subscribe to this point?

I make service for sending messages, and I want to be able to create for each delivery process one queue. And manage this Q. But consumers needs to be subscribed on all of this Q

The idea of gathering all the queues at one point and pick up messages from this point
But how to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

In RabbitMQ, usually messages should be published to "exchanges" and consumed from "queues". And there are bindings between exchanges and queues. In your case, naturally, you could create exchanges for each of your senders, and bind these exchanges all to one queue for consuming.

Comment: In your variant is not possible to ask system about number of processed messages.
But i making follow solutiuon:
one main queue

Comment: In your variant is not possible to ask system about a number of processed messages.
But I making follow solution:
One main queue and a lot of queues for each delivery/sender (additional Qs). Workers subscribe only on the main Q, but messages in main Q contains fields with the name of additional Q. 
So worker gets message from main and additional Q. In anytime I can ask rabbitMQ about the number of messages in addQ. Or I can delete this Q and stop the delivery process. 
Maybe this is strange architecture, but it satisfies my needs

Comment: Ok, I almost got your point. So you are saying you want to, for instance, have 3 senders and 3 sender queues (one for each sender); you expects messages in sender queues be gathered into a gather queue; your subscriber only subscribes to the gather queue, right? There is one question, do you want the gathering process to be automatic? If it is automatic, as long as any message is sent to a sender queue, it is removed from the sender queue and gathered to the gather queue, then if you try to get number of messages in the sender queues, it will always be 0.

Comment: If your gathering process is not automatic, then you have to write an app with custom logic for when to gather which sender queues.

Comment: And if the automatic way is what you want, then the sender queues will have no benefits comparing to use sender exchanges instead (coz the queue length will always be 0, and you don't need an additional gather app for gathering messages if you use exchanges).